# Placing fixed height div at bottom in container with another div using whatever space is left

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined below container as content of the cell in a 3rd party javascript library (dhtmlx). What I am trying to do is create a container that has two divs, where one has a fixed height at the bottom and one can have varied height taking up the rest of the space.

Have searched around here, and have tried to do some of the suggestions, but the top space seem to ignore the padding-bottom and shows content behind the bottom fixed div. How can I set up the style to allow that to happen?

```
    var sContainer = "<div id='paging_containerDetails_{0}' style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: #B5CDE4 1px solid;'>".format(oTabProps.ID);
    sContainer += "<div id='gridDetails_{0}' style='position: relative; padding-bottom: 30px; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:white;overflow:auto;'></div>".format(oTabProps.ID);
    sContainer += "<div id='recDetailsinfoArea_{0}' style='position: absolute;bottom: 0; overflow: auto;width:100%;height:30px;'></div>".format(oTabProps.ID);
    sContainer += "</div>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
.top{height: calc(100% - 100px); width: 100%; background-color: red;}
```

The `calc()` will let you set `100% - the height` of the bottom `<div>`

See Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ff0k9j45/5/

Comment: Thanks, this seem to work on ie11, if I put in height: calc(100% - 30px) instead of height: 100%, however it does not seem to work for ie8. Any idea how to do this for earlier versions of ie?

Comment: I am not to sure, all my sites block ie8 so I don't really know. I can tell you though that ie10 and below will no longer be supported by microsoft in January so it might not be a big deal ;)

Comment: I wished I could do that :) However I have users on MS Servers with strict company policy as to not upgrade anything from what they came with out of the box... Tried using box-sizing and padding-bottom to no use.